# Count char occurs in string with length 10^200

Tags: c++, string

I have a string on Linux standard terminal input. Its maximal length is 10^200 (as said in program specification). I have to count, how many "3" characters are inside it (occur in this string). I couldn't do that by for loop, because there is no so big variable type, which can be used as iterator. Is there any way to analyze so big strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to analyze so big strings?

Not in this universe there is not. Such an entity cannot exist in this universe<sup>1</sup> and that which does not exist, cannot be analyzed.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Current estimates of this universe's total number of particles particles are in the region of 10<sup>80</sup>.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

As from your comment

> The data source is standard terminal input.

Then you'll need a lot of monkeys to type this in.

Though you don't need to read in what's typed at once into a big string, but you can simply analyze `char` by `char` as typed. The [`std::istream::get(char_type& ch)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get%29) method is suitable for doing so.

Comment: +1 for figuring out what the real question is.